# Protect files from `rm -f`

Tags: permissions, rm

Much to my immediate chagrin, removing write permission from a file does not seem to protect it from `rm -f`:

```
touch foo
chmod a-w foo
rm -f foo
```

How can I protect a file from accidental deletion when `rm` will be called with the `-f` flag? It looks like `chattr +i foo` would work, but it requires root on my system (is that intended?), so I'm looking for a non-root solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To prevent files from being added or deleted to a directory, you can to remove the write permission for the directory.

Comment: Good idea, didn't think about protecting the directory. That's 1/2 of the way there, is it possible to protect a single file in a directory, but leave the others mutable?

Comment: @Hooked No, this is how Unix works. If you want to keep the directory's write bit, but also preserve some files inside it, you can hardlink them from another directory without write permission.

Comment: @angus: this should not prevent the deletion of the file. At the end it should be no different than having a backup.

Comment: @enzotib It won't prevent unlinking the link from the mixed directory, but it does ensure the file doesn't disappear altogether if it's accidentally deleted from there..

Answer (score 0):

Write permission on a file allows for changing the contents of a file, write permission on a folder allows for changing the contents of a folder (ie which files are in the folder).

Most filesystems allow for certain other attributetes. You *might* be interrested in the 'immutable' attribute. `sudo chattr +i file` disables editing, moving, deleting and linking to the file.

Comment: On a tangent, if you add the attribute +a on a log, it will never be truncated. Use this and `histappend -a` to keep your shell log forever.

Comment: `chmod a-w .` protects the current directory.